# \textbf don't work "I work with latex for macbook"

Tags: polyglossia

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia} \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Traditional Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\begin{document}

\textbf{ليكن}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does typeface have a bold font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because there is no bold version of that font.

A font with bold works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia} \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\textbf{ليكن}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I must work. with Amiri ?

Comment: An other solution I download "traditional arabic bold"

Comment: Well, if the font does not have bold, and you want bold, you must work with a font that has bold, or fake a bold version of the font that does not have bold.